# Read value from multiple similar tags with attributes

Tags: php, simplexml

I have an .xml file which looks like this:

```
<Products>
<Product>
    <Denumire>Carcasa rigida THULE Legend GoPro, black (TLGC101)</Denumire>
    <Cod>TLGC101</Cod>

    <Atribut denumire="Tip">geanta/husa</Atribut>
    <Atribut denumire="Compatibilitate">GoPro</Atribut>
    <Atribut denumire="Dimensiuni">150 x 210 x 80 mm (exterior), 35 x 185 x 125 mm (interior)</Atribut>
    <Atribut denumire="Greutate">0.24 kg</Atribut>
    <Atribut denumire="Culoare">negru</Atribut>
    <Atribut denumire="Altele">interior spuma EVA</Atribut>
    <Atribut denumire="Cod">TLGC101</Atribut>
</Product>
```

I just can't find a way to extract the values of "Atribut" tags ("geanta/husa", "GoPro" and so on). My code looks like this:

```
    $products = simplexml_load_file("http://abc.xyz/feed.xml");
foreach($products->Product as $prod)
    {   
        foreach($prod->Atribut as $key=>$atr)
            {
                //extract the value for "denumire" attribute
                $nume_atribut = (string)$atr->attributes()[0];

                //get the value of the "Atribut" tag
            }
    }
```

Dumping the $prod->Atribut gives me:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (8) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["denumire"]=>
    string(3) "Tip"
  }
  [0]=>
  string(11) "geanta/husa"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "GoPro"
  [2]=>
  string(58) "150 x 210 x 80 mm (exterior), 35 x 185 x 125 mm (interior)"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "0.24 kg"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "negru"
  [5]=>
  string(18) "interior spuma EVA"
  [6]=>
  string(7) "TLGC101"
}
```

... while dumping $prod->Atribut[0] gives:

> object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (1) {   ["@attributes"]=>   array(1) {
>       ["denumire"]=>
>       string(3) "Tip"   } }

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use method __toString of SimpleXMLElement directly:

```
$atr->__toString()
```

or use type casting (actually it will use __toString internally):

```
(string)$atr
```

Comment: Thanks! (string)$atr did the trick, the other method returned a void object.